# Aspectj not work when use ant to do compile

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

If I use IDE to run the code,  everything works fine.
[image]

But when i use ant to compile the code, Aspectj's proxy doesn't work.
My ant target

```
   <property name="ajc.adapter" value="org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ajc11CompilerAdapter"/> 
   <target name="compile" description="compile all files">
    <mkdir dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" />
       <javac
           debug="true"
           srcdir="src"
           destdir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"
           classpathref="classpath"
           deprecation="true"
           source="1.6"
           target="1.6"
           optimize="true">
           <include name="**/*.java" />
           <compilerarg compiler="${ajc.adapter}" line="-verbose -Xlint -proceedOnError"/>
           <compilerarg compiler="${ajc.adapter}" value="-classpath"/>
           <!--<compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation"/>-->
           <!--<compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>-->
       </javac>
    <!-- Copy the properties files. -->
    <copy todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.properties" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- Copy the XML files -->
    <copy todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Java code :

```
    @Around("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(com.xyz.MonitorMethod)")
public Object check(ProceedingJoinPoint  pjp) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("======================222");
    }
}
```

Is any issue in this target? THX.
I want use [Ajc11CompilerAdapter (javac)](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/antTasks-adapter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not running `ajc` at all in your ant target, just standard `javac`.

Please refer to `ajc` [ant task documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/antTasks-iajc.html)

EDIT: (listing the rough steps from the page above):

- add `aspectjtools.jar` into ant's lib directory
- modify your `javac` target using following for guidance guidance:

  ```
   <property name="ajc"
       value="org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ajc11CompilerAdapter"/>

   <javac srcdir="src" includes="org/aspectj/**/*.java" destdir="dest" >
       <compilerarg compiler="${ajc}" line="-argfile src/args.lst"/>
   <javac/>
  ```
- run your build script passing the `build.compiler` property with value of fully qualified name of the adapter class:
  `Ant -Dbuild.compiler=org.aspectj.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ajc11CompilerAdapter`

(I can't tell why you would pass it as command line argument AND define it as property within the script either)

Comment: Actually  I want use Ajc11CompilerAdapter (javac), Do you have any idea how to follow this doc? https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/antTasks-adapter.html

Comment: Thank you, i will do some investigate.

Comment: @diginoise can you help me , this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930247/when-run-ant-script-aspectj-not-import-aspect-source-folder-out-side-java-class